# derivative with product rule

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to take the derivative of this function. First, I want to take the derivative of the original function, $F(x,\eta)$, with respect to $\eta$:

$$F(x,\eta)=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}g(1,\eta)\frac{x}{[1+C(\eta)(x-1)]^3}$$

Do not worry about what $g(1,\eta)$ and $C(\eta)$ are, just know that they are both just functions of $\eta$

So, if I want to that the derivative with respect to $\eta$, this is my attempt. I was hoping someone could check the work  to make sure it looks ok.

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}\left[g'(1,\eta)\frac{x}{[1+C(\eta)(x-1)]^3}+g(1,\eta)\left(\frac{x}{3[1+C(\eta)(x-1)]^2}*\frac{1}{C'(\eta)(x-1)}\right)\right]$$

If this looks ok, I'll try and take the derivative with respect to $x$ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second term has some problems, it should be something like

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}\left[g'(1,\eta) \frac{x}{[1 + C(\eta)(x - 1)]^3} - 3g(1,\eta)\left(\frac{x(x -1 )C'(\eta)}{[1 + C(\eta)(x-1)]^4}\right)\right]
$$

which just comes from

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\eta} \frac{1}{[f(\eta)]^3} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\eta} [f(\eta)]^{-3} = -3[f(\eta)]^{-4}\frac{{\rm d}f(\eta)}{{\rm d}\eta} = -3\frac{1}{[f(\eta)]^4} \frac{{\rm d}f(\eta)}{{\rm d}\eta}
$$

Similarly, if you take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ you should obtain

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}g(1,\eta)\left[\frac{1}{[1 + C(\eta)(x - 1)]^3} -\frac{3 x C(\eta)}{[1 + C(\eta)(x -1)]^4}\right]
$$

Comment: Ok, so I see what you did, just curious though - What is the assumption that I made that is wrong? I just took the derivative, but just 1 over it. I guess I just want to know why my way is wrong, what is the wrong assumption that I am making?

Comment: @JacksonHart You are using this

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\eta} \frac{1}{f(\eta)} = \frac{1}{{\rm d}f/{\rm d}\eta}
$$

which is **not** true, that is the assumption that is breaking your results

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the help! Any chance you could also show what the solution would be for the derivative with respect to x?

Comment: actually, I think there may be a mistake in your solution. You have $(x-1)^3$, but note that this ^3 was outside the whole thing, not just the $x-1$. Do you see what I am talking about? The cubed is outside what you refer to as $f(\eta)$

Comment: @JacksonHart Solution updated